# How to change black color to Red with OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-editing

How can you make it in Python? I faced a problem with this line

```
img_rgb.Set(mask,cv2.Scalar(0,0,255))
```

and here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import imutils

import cv2

img_rgb = cv2.imread('figi.jpg')

Conv_hsv_Gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, mask = cv2.threshold(Conv_hsv_Gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV |cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

img_rgb.Set(mask,cv2.Scalar(0,0,255))

cv2.imshow("imgOriginal", img_rgb)  # show windows

cv2.imshow("output", res)  # show windows

cv2.imshow("mask", mask)  # show windows

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: what was the problem? the red is actually blue? crash? tell us more.

Comment: cv2.THRES_OTSU will determine the threshold automatically and probably it will not be pure black color. Try ret, mask = cv2.threshold(Conv_hsv_Gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) or `ret, mask = cv2.threshold(Conv_hsv_Gray, 1, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)` (not sure whether thres value is inclusive or exclusive) instead. Please post your input image too, jpeg might introduce some artifacts so that "black" might not be "pure black".

Comment: the input image is : http://i.stack.imgur.com/FjEXu.jpg
and the output image is : http://i.stack.imgur.com/vhb67.png

im changing the black color in the image and Convert it to the Red color cuz the intensty of the Red Color is more than the black so After the changing it will easy to track the black objects without eny disturb

Comment: I remember that image. since it is not perfect black the OTSU version will be good ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The API for `mat.setTo()` is not available in Opencv module for python, this is due to the reason that in `C++` Opencv uses `cv::Mat` object as basic entity for image manipulation, However in Python there is no such `cv::Mat` concept, instead Python API for Opencv uses the well known library `numpy` for image manipulation operations, and numpy has a very beautiful syntax to set the values using a mask:

```
img_rgb[mask == 255] = [0, 0, 255]
```

Simply replacing this line with the `img_rgb.Set(mask,cv2.Scalar(0,0,255))` would get your work done.