# How to change a range of RGB colors to Red with OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-3.7, image-editing

From [How to change black color to Red with OpenCV Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058177/how-to-change-the-black-color-to-red-with-opencv-python) I found this code

```
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2
img_rgb = cv2.imread('black.png')
Conv_hsv_Gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(Conv_hsv_Gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV |cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
img_rgb[mask == 255] = [0, 0, 255]
cv2.imshow("imgOriginal", img_rgb)  # show windows
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)  # show windows
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

is there any way i could change the line

```
img_rgb[mask == 255] = [0, 0, 255]
```

or something else to make it change a range of colors?
for example:

```
([255, 255, 0], [255, 55, 10])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can.

First, you must create a mask of the color range to change, and the answer for that is the [inRange function of OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981).

Then, via numpy, you can say where the mask is not 0 paint them in my image red. This is the code for that:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# load image and set the bounds
img = cv2.imread("D:\\debug\\HLS.png")
lower =(255, 55, 0) # lower bound for each channel
upper = (255, 255, 10) # upper bound for each channel

# create the mask and use it to change the colors
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
img[mask != 0] = [0,0,255]

# display it
cv2.imshow("frame", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If you want actually to get a range of colors (e.g. all blue colors) it is better to use HLS or HSV color spaces.

Comment: when i run it i get an error message,
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Blake/Desktop/Python3.7/opencvtests2.py", line 10, in <module>
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv- 
    python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1761: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ! 
    _src.empty() in function 'cv::inRange'

Comment: @R4nsomW4re it says that the image is empty... so make sure img was loaded correctly :)

Comment: If you want actually to get a range of colors (e.g. all blue colors) it is better to use HLS or HSV color spaces. ---> could you please give us an example of that

Comment: @pippo1980 it is basically the same example, the difference is that you convert it after loading (using cvtcolor) and then the channel with the H (Hue) is basically the color. You need to get the range the represents the desire color, for example blue. I have answered other questions using this, but I couldnt find it