# Highlight the changes or areas of discrepancy between the two images

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-editing

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

These are my images, I want to

- Convert the PDF documents (`file_1.pdf` and `file_2.pdf`) into images.
- Compare the images to detect any differences between them.
- Highlight the changes or areas of discrepancy between the two images.

This is my code

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from IPython.display import display`

def process_and_display_image(pdf_path, target_size=(800, 600),save_path='processed_image.jpeg'):
    images = convert_from_path(pdf_path)
    image = images[0]
    image = ImageOps.exif_transpose(image)
    image.thumbnail(target_size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    image_np = np.array(image)
    image_np = cv2.cvtColor(image_np, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    image_processed = Image.fromarray(image_np)
    display(image_processed)
    image_processed.save(save_path, 'JPEG')
    print(f"Image saved as {save_path}")

# Display image from PDF
process_and_display_image("file_1.pdf",save_path='file_1.jpeg')
process_and_display_image("file_2.pdf",save_path='file_2.jpeg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image1 = cv2.imread('file_1.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image2 = cv2.imread('file_2.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

if image1.shape == image2.shape:
    difference = cv2.absdiff(image1,image2)
difference = 255 - difference

if image1.shape == image2.shape:
    
    overlay = cv2.addWeighted(image1, 0.5, image2, 0.5, 0) 
       
difference = overlay
plt.imshow(difference)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

My output is -> [image: My_output]

Expected output -> [image: Expected output]

Comment: is this a homework? There was a similar (in terms of images) question yesterday

Comment: This is not exactly my homework question, I was just practising and I have been stuck on this question since few days :(

Comment: @cards yep, spent 2 hours answering a question that was delete. Should I put my time on this ?

Comment: @pippo1980 Sorry I wasn't able to frame that question clearly that's why I have had to delete that question. Actually I was new and I didn't know properly how to post a question. I apologise to you for deleting that previous question and wasting your time. It would be a great help if you will help me again.
Thank You for helping me :).

Comment: dont worry , I am learning OpenCV too ... And your question now is more clear.

Comment: could you please provide better-resolved data? those are almost thumbnails, or were they screenshots? also take care to make sure the *data* lines up. if your process of making those pictures introduces misalignment, take care to fix that. if the alignment is inherent to the problem, then why does that happen?

Comment: Actually these are the images that I have had extracted from the pdf files after converting them into a given taget size and also doing exif_transpose

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz , they seemed aligned to me , upper corner first gray pixel has same x,y in both images

Comment: if you open both pictures and switch between them, you'll see some slight misalignment. of course, I'm talking about the architectural information, not the frame around the page.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  yes thanks , pixel seem at the same location (x,y)  their color values are different, so its not the same .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to present some simple operations to get exactly the colors you want, without thresholding.

`im1` and `im2` (grayscale):

[image: im1]
[image: im2]

```py
# assuming white sheet of paper, ink is the inverse
# positive = added
# negative = deleted
signed_difference = (255 - im2).astype(np.int16) - (255 - im1).astype(np.int16)
```

[image: signed_difference]

<sup>(white = added, black = removed. If you need to look at it, `imshow("window", signed_difference / (255*2) + 0.5)`)</sup>

Starting from a version that contains only "ink" that's in both pictures, I'll add colored "ink" for the additions and deletions. The `reshape` and `expand_dims` stuff helps numpy do the right thing.

```py
canvas = np.maximum(im1, im2) # same ink in both images
canvas = cv.cvtColor(canvas, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# add colored ink: subtract the inverse of those colors to "ink" the page

add_color = np.array([255, 128, 0]).reshape((1, 1, 3)) # additions blue
del_color = np.array([0, 0, 255]).reshape((1, 1, 3)) # deletions red

strength = np.expand_dims(np.abs(signed_difference) / 255, axis=2)

# those are just for knowing *what pixels* are affected at all.
# results are all grayscale, no thresholding.
add_mask = np.expand_dims(signed_difference > 0, axis=2)
del_mask = np.expand_dims(signed_difference < 0, axis=2)

canvas = np.where(add_mask, canvas - (255 - add_color) * strength, canvas)
canvas = np.where(del_mask, canvas - (255 - del_color) * strength, canvas)
canvas = np.clip(canvas, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

[image: canvas]

And that's it.

---

You'll want to make sure your pictures are aligned well, even **sub-pixel accurately**. You can use [`findTransformECC()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga1aa357007eaec11e9ed03500ecbcbe47) for sub-pixel refinement.

The worse the initial alignment, the more blurring (`gaussFiltSize`) you'll need. All kinds of "fixed borders" will ruin this process. Make sure to only feed the "art" in, not any framing.

The core of that operation:

```py
H = np.eye(3).astype(np.float32)

(rv, H) = cv.findTransformECC(
    templateImage=im1,
    inputImage=im2,
    warpMatrix=H[:2],
    motionType=cv.MOTION_AFFINE,
    criteria=(cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 20, -1), # -1 to ignore eps and use all iterations
    inputMask=None,
    gaussFiltSize=5
)

im2_aligned = cv.warpAffine(im2, H, (im1.shape[1], im1.shape[0]), flags=cv.INTER_CUBIC + cv.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
```

And this is what your input looks like, aligned and colored, without borders:

[image]

---

You'll notice that it also colors gray-to-gray differences. Your reference picture does not show that. Your reference picture was probably made by the original CAD program. The CAD program is aware of the geometry and colors it according to flexible styles. *I* can only work on the image data. Sure, it's possible to exclude "gray" from the coloring but then you'll also see the gray pixels near black pixels (fuzzy lines) *not-colored*.

Here's a complete gray-to-gray display:

[image: im1]
[image: im2]

[image: signed_difference]
[image: result]

Comment: HI @ChristophRackwitz , sorry to bother could you post more on signed_difference = (255 - im2).astype(np.uint16) - (255 - im1).astype(np.uint16) , also any tricks to visualize it , I got almost black picture in cv.imshow()  and displaying signed_difference*256 still has black background that cover the black lines

Comment: got it cv2.normalize(signed_difference , None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

Answer (score 0):

My attempt using `1.jpg` and `2.jpg` as input files, so I had to trim your code concerning the *convert pdf to image* , and I added two funcs I copied somewhere here on SO to better visualize the results on my enviroment , code :

```
# from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
# from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    if width is None and height is None:
        return image
    if width is None:
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    else:
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)


draw_windows = True  ## change fo False for no windows only calc


def drawWindow(window_name, image):
    if draw_windows:
        
        resize = ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width= 500)
        
        cv2.imshow(window_name, resize)
        
        cv2.moveWindow(window_name, 600, 200)
        
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# def process_and_display_image(pdf_path, target_size=(800, 600),save_path='processed_image.jpeg'):
#     images = convert_from_path(pdf_path)
#     image = images[0]
#     image = ImageOps.exif_transpose(image)
#     image.thumbnail(target_size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
#     image_np = np.array(image)
#     image_np = cv2.cvtColor(image_np, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
#     image_processed = Image.fromarray(image_np)
#     display(image_processed)
#     image_processed.save(save_path, 'JPEG')
#     print(f"Image saved as {save_path}")

# # Display image from PDF
# process_and_display_image("file_1.pdf",save_path='file_1.jpeg')
# process_and_display_image("file_2.pdf",save_path='file_2.jpeg')

# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##READ IMAGE 1
image1 = cv2.imread('1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)


image1_gray = image1.copy()


## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058177/how-to-change-the-black-color-to-red-with-opencv-python
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(image1_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV |cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

image1_copy = image1.copy()

print('mask : ', mask.shape , mask.size, mask.ndim , np.min(mask) , np.max(mask), len(np.unique(mask)))

image1[mask == 255] = [0, 0, 255]

drawWindow('image1', image1)

cv2.imwrite('image1_red.png' , image1)

print('image1 : ', image1.shape , image1.size, image1.ndim , np.min(image1) 
                  
                          , np.max(image1), len(np.unique(image1)))



##READ IMAGE 2
image2 = cv2.imread('2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

image2_gray = image2.copy()

ret, mask = cv2.threshold(image2_gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV |cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

image2_copy = image2.copy()

image2[mask == 255] = [255, 0, 0]

drawWindow('image2', image2)

cv2.imwrite('image2_blue.png' , image2)


if image1.shape == image2.shape:
    
    overlay = cv2.addWeighted(image1, 0.5, image2, 0.5, 0) 
       
difference = overlay


print('difference : ', difference.shape , difference.size, difference.ndim ,
      
                  np.min(difference) , np.max(difference), len(np.unique(difference)))


drawWindow('difference', difference)


cv2.imwrite('difference.png' , difference)


difference2 = np.where((image1_copy == image2_copy) , image1_copy , difference)


print('difference2 : ', difference2.shape , difference2.size, difference2.ndim ,
      
                  np.min(difference2) , np.max(difference2), len(np.unique(difference2)))


drawWindow('difference2', difference2)


cv2.imwrite('difference2.png' , difference2)



diffs = difference2 - difference

print('diffs : ', diffs.shape , diffs.size, diffs.ndim ,
      
                  np.min(diffs) , np.max(diffs), len(np.unique(diffs)))


drawWindow('diffs', diffs)


cv2.imwrite('diffs.png' , diffs)


plt.imshow(difference2)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

have a look at `difference.png` :

[image]

and `difference2.png` see the upper corner at pixel magnification to get differences :

[image]

last just differences between `difference.png` and `difference2.png` ; `diffs.png`

adding this two lines instead of `diffs = difference2 - difference`

```
zero = np.ones((difference.shape[0],difference.shape[1],difference.shape[2])).astype('uint8')*255

diffs = np.where(difference2 == difference , zero , difference2)
```

would have got a better looking picture with white background
:

[image]

Wasnt able to get exactly your output , something is eluding my logic, but this is my best effort, let us know if you find a better faster solution.
I capitalized on [How to change black color to Red with OpenCV Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058177/how-to-change-the-black-color-to-red-with-opencv-python) to get the red and blue images, don't know if there is a way to find a better solution that could ease the identification of just the different parts in the output images where my :

`difference2 = np.where((image1_copy == image2_copy) , image1_copy , difference)`

fails to accomplish the expected result